# ElasticSearch Update failing because of tag name?

Tags: elasticsearch

For my given ElasticSearch document, I can update the value of a particular field named "ResourcePort".  But the update fails with "Illegal Argument Exception" when I try and update the field name "Domain.threat".  Is it because the field name has a "dot" in it?  My code running in the sense plugin is

```
 POST /foo/bar/12/_update
 {"script":"ctx._source.Domain.threat='bad'"}
```

But this works

```
 POST /foo/bar/12/_update
 {"script":"ctx._source.ResourcePort='bad'"}
```

EDITED:
My ES version is 1.1.0
The Domain.threat field is "Domain.threat":{"type":"string"}

Comment: What does the actual object look like? And which version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: I updated the original repost to hopefully answer your question.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. What is the actual `IllegalArgumentException`? I did not have any issue with this on 1.1.0. I am guessing that the object being updated does not actually have a `Domain` object to hold the `threat`, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is that you have not mapped domain as a nested field.
make sure you have set Domain as -:

```
  {
      "properties": {
        "Domain": {
          "type": "nested", 
          "properties": {
            "threat":    { "type": "string"  }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```